# Google sheet how to keep formula while getting answer in google form BY USING IFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

```
=ifs(D2="Bagumbayan","Christian", D2="Central", "Danilo ")
```

The Above code is what i use to Fill My Column B

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Bagumbayan | Christian |
| Central | Danilo |

But when i got a new answer in Google  Form the formula is not applying. It just keep getting new row. I tried using Array Formula like this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(Ifs(""&D2:D="Bagumbayan","Christian Joshua P Mendigoria", ""&D2="Central", "Danilo Garcia"))))
```

But i always getting #N/A i already tried placing arrayformula after "if" and before REGMATCH but i walys getting #N//A

Can anyone please point me to something on what i did wrong here? i'm having a hard time with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use `indirect()` to hard-lock the range as such & place the formula in row_1 of any column of choice (say Cell_X1 or Y1 or so...):*

```js
=let(Σ,indirect("D2:D"),
     vstack("Header_",arrayformula(ifs(Σ="Bagumbayan","Christian", Σ="Central","Danilo", 1,))))
```